# Write $-\Delta u = f(x,u,Du)$ as fixed point problem

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let $f \in C(\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}^n)$.
How can I write $$-\Delta u = f(x,u,Du)$$
in $\mathbb{R}^n$ as a fixed point problem?

Comment: nice question.  I edited your post just a tad--you left out the closing \$ sign in your first "equaton".

Comment: @RobertLewis Thank you.

Comment: My pleasure, sir!

Comment: @Riku--this isn't really a Cauchy problem as stated.  Where are the time derivatives $D_tu$, $D_{tt}u$, etc?  Note that as stated, $g(x)$ must solve $-\Delta g = f(0, x, g, D_xg)$, an elliptic problem methinks!

Comment: Some musings.  I'm not sure about on all of $\mathbb R^n$, but on a small open subset, you might be able to get local solvability.  If you apply a parametrix $P$ (pseudo-inverse of the Laplacian) to both sides, then $P\circ f$ is (formally) a pseudo-differential operator of order -1, hence a compact operator from $C_c\to C$ by Rellich's lemma.

Comment: @user254433 Thanks for the remarks. I'm actually just interested in writing the problem as a fixed point problem (for example a fixed point problem for a convolution of the fundamental solution of the Laplace equation with $f$).