# Existence of smooth solutions for $-\Delta u = f(x,u,Du,D^2u)$ or $-\Delta u = f(x,u,Du)$

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, partial-differential-equations

Let $f \in C(\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^{n\times n})$ and Lipschitz in $u$, $Du,D^2u$.

- How can I prove that $$-\Delta u = f(x,u,Du,D^2u)$$
  in $\mathbb{R}^n$ has a **smooth solution**?
- Does the result hold if we only consider $f(x,u,Du)$ instead of $f(x,u,Du,D^2u)$?

Comment: Slightly related question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2304910/write-delta-u-fx-u-du-as-fixed-point-problem

Comment: Let us define $f(x,u,Du,D^2u) := -\operatorname{trace}(D^2 u)$. Then the solution is certainly not unique.

Comment: @gerw That is correct. It remains to solve the problem of existence.